# forge.facebook.authorize not redirecting for website

Tags: facebook, trigger.io, forge

I have a trigger.io app working fine using facebook authentication on Android and iPhone, however, when I publish it locally for web via Chrome clicking on the "Connect to facebook" button does not call the forge.facebook.authorize function. There is no output of it failing either. Help?

```
forge.logging.info("Facebook pressed!");

            forge.facebook.authorize(['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_about_me'], function () {
                forge.logging.info("Facebook success");

                forge.facebook.api('/me', function (response) {
                    FBLoginOrCreateAccount(response);
                }, function () {
                    forge.logging.info("facebook graph call failed.");
                    $(".loading").hide();
                });
            }, function (e) {
                forge.logging.info("facebook failed: " + JSON.stringify(e));
                $(".loading").hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our Facebook SDK integration is for mobile platforms only:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/facebook.html#facebook-authorize

What you should do is branch your code using [forge.is.web()](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/is.html#web) and use Facebook's normal oauth and REST API for your web version.

Answer (score 0):

www.facebook.com

```
        forge.logging.info("Facebook pressed!");

        forge.facebook.authorize(['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_about_me'], function () {
            forge.logging.info("Facebook success");

            forge.facebook.api('/me', function (response) {
                FBLoginOrCreateAccount(response);
            }, function () {
                forge.logging.info("facebook graph call failed.");
                $(".loading").hide();
            });
        }, function (e) {
            forge.logging.info("facebook failed: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            $(".loading").hide();
        });
```